# Getting refresh token each time

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am trying to get the refresh token every time the following uri is called,

```
String link = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token/?code=" + code + "&" + "client_id=" + client_id + "&" + "client_secret=" + client_secret + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "app/email/emailSetupController/gmailutil&" + "grant_type=authorization_code&" + "access_type=offline&" + "approval_prompt=force";
```

However the `approval_prompt=force` is not working as it should ask for users approval every time in order to get a refresh token.
I also tried `prompt=consent`. If the user has already logged in the gmail account then it does not show the approval page and redirects automatically resulting in refresh token as null.

Comment: Gmail-api? I doubt you are actually using their Java API if you creating a string like that.. expand your questing with more lines than just a string. Secondly, have you looked at the actual API lib provided by google? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Comment: Looking at [this](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/453) issue it seems like `approval_prompt=force`got replaced by `prompt=consent`, have you tried using only the last solution?

Comment: @Signo I did try the prompt=consent. but it still does not ask for users approval page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad, actually the above URI is for "Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens" instead the prompt=consent is to be used in the first step while setting the authorization parameters[Google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl).

Thank you.